# how to fix javascript tmlanguage highlighting bug

Tags: vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting, tmlanguage

I'm making a VS Code extension for xml, but the if statements occurs highlighting bug. The code is below

```xml
<script><![CDATA[
if () {
}]]></script>
```

[image: bug img]

however, `if (){` works normally

```xml
<script><![CDATA[
if (){
}]]></script>
```

[image: normal img]

even function statements too.

I tried modifying "if-statement", all of "end": "\}", "(?=\})"
but failed to fix it

my tmlanguage expr is (source.scxml)
and only fixed comment expr of source.js

```json
{
    "name": "source.js.embedded.scxml",
    "begin": "(<!)(\\[)(CDATA\\[)",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "1": {"name": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin.scxml"},
        "2": {"name": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin.scxml"},
        "3": {"name": "entity.other.attribute-name.scxml"}
    },
    "end": "(\\])(\\])(>)",
    "endCaptures": {
        "1": {"name": "entity.other.attribute-name.scxml"},
        "2": {"name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.scxml"},
        "3": {"name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.scxml"}
    },
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "source.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

additionally similar bug

```xml
<script><![CDATA[
//test]]></script>
```

highlighting error fixed at source.js

```json
{
    "name": "comment.block.js",
    "begin": "(/\\*)(?:\\s*((@)internal)(?=\\s|(\\*/)))?",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "1": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "storage.type.internaldeclaration.js"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "punctuation.decorator.internaldeclaration.js"
        }
    },
    "end": "\\*/",
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        }
    }
},
{
    "begin": "(^[ \\t]+)?((//)(?:\\s*((@)internal)(?=\\s|$))?)",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "1": {
            "name": "punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.js"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "comment.line.double-slash.js"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        },
        "4": {
            "name": "storage.type.internaldeclaration.js"
        },
        "5": {
            "name": "punctuation.decorator.internaldeclaration.js"
        }
    },
    "end": "(?=$)",
    "contentName": "comment.line.double-slash.js"
}
```

to

```json
{
    "name": "comment.block.js",
    "begin": "(/\\*)(?:\\s*((@)internal)(?=\\s|(\\*/)))?",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "1": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "storage.type.internaldeclaration.js"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "punctuation.decorator.internaldeclaration.js"
        }
    },
    "end": "\\*/",
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        }
    }
},
{
    "begin": "(^[ \\t]+)?((//)(?:\\s*((@)internal)(?=\\s|$))?)",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "1": {
            "name": "punctuation.whitespace.comment.leading.js"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "comment.line.double-slash.js"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.js"
        },
        "4": {
            "name": "storage.type.internaldeclaration.js"
        },
        "5": {
            "name": "punctuation.decorator.internaldeclaration.js"
        }
    },
    "end": "(?=\\]\\]>|$)",
    "contentName": "comment.line.double-slash.js"
}
```